# db2 naming strategy problem after migration to springboot 3

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, db2

All worked fine before migration to springboot 3, but after migration I have a problem with DB field names. In code all entities have a names in fieldName (camel case), that converted into field_name in DB.

```
class MyEntity{
@Id
private long id;
private String fieldName;
}
```

in application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

In spring-bot 2 was all fine, but in 3 got an error "

> missing column [fieldName] in table [TABLE_NAME1]

if I delete naming-strategy properties it comes to other error  "missing sequence [table2_seq]"

But i don't have this sequence and don't need it, but hibernate trying to find it. It seems like conflict in naming strategies.
I understand, that I can fix problem with field names with `@Column(name="field_name")` annotation, but it's not a best solution.

Question: how to fix this naming conflict in other (best practice) way?